# How to check that Vertica backup (or database) is in valid state?

Tags: database-backups, vertica

How to check that Vertica backup (or database) is in valid state and I can restore database from it without problems?

P.S.

Several days ago I have a very negative experience with Vertica backup: `vbr` create backups from broken database. When I tried to restore database from such "backup" the `vbr` utility restore it but I couldn't to start database (Vertica run recovering process and finish it with error). Seems like `vbr` doesn't check state of database before backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 7.2.2, vbr can do integrity checks on backups.  From the [documentation](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.2.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/BackupRestore/CheckingBackupIntegrity.htm):

> A quick check gathers all backup metadata from the backup location specified in the configuration file and compares that metadata to the backup manifest. A quick check does not verify the objects themselves. Instead, this task outputs an exceptions list of any discrepancies between objects in the backup location and objects listed in the backup manifest.
>
> [...] A full check verifies all objects listed in the backup manifest against file system metadata. A full check includes the same steps as a quick check.

The command is:

```
vbr -t [quick-check | full-check] -c configfile.ini --report-file=path/filename
```

Comment: Excellent! Now I have a reason for migration from 7.1.x to 7.2.x. Thank you.

Comment: And 8.0 is coming soon, according to announcements this week.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at [Talena](http://www.talena-inc.com) software (my company) if you are interested in granular backup and recovery of your vertica database as well as other databases such as Cassandra, Hadoop, etc.